# ANTD Select mode="multiple" is slow when trying to implement select/de-select all

Tags: reactjs, select, drop-down-menu, antd, react-select

I have a list of not more than 30 items. But when I click on select all and then de-select or deselect only one item page freezes for a certain time and then again backs to normal with updated checked or unchecked values. I am not getting what is happening.
It is an issue of antd select itself or it is because toggle select/deselect causing this delay maybe because the whole list is re-rendering very frequently.
Also, in the console, I get something like this,

```
[Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 109ms
[Violation] 'click' handler took 206ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 72ms
[Violation] 'click' handler took 204ms
[Violation] 'click' handler took 390ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 180ms
[Violation] 'animationend' handler took 13282ms
[Violation] 'animationend' handler took 13341ms
[Violation] Forced reflow while executing JavaScript took 12864ms
[Violation] 'click' handler took 171ms
```

ANTD Select - https://ant.design/components/select/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the code where you used antd select?

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a [known issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/10431) in the AntD component itself with no forthcoming solution as of right now.

Apart from maintaining a fork of AntD and trying to optimize the re-renders yourself, the only real solution is to use a different library for managing data.  I'd recommend looking at [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/), [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized), or [react-base-table](https://github.com/Autodesk/react-base-table), though there are certainly others.